# The limits of $(x_n,x_n)$ in the diagonal of a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, limits, solution-verification

In question 2 of [this](https://www.isibang.ac.in/%7Estatmath/oldqp/Sol/Topology%20Sol%202015-16.pdf) exam we see that topological space $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x)\in X\times X\}$ is a closed. I came across this theorem in a similar assignment question and I am happy with the proof and validity of this theorem.

However, an equivalent definition of closed is that a subspace contains all its limit points. As far as I am concerned a sequence $x_i\in X$ converges exactly when $(x_i,x_i)\in X\times X$ converges and if $x_i\rightarrow x$ then surely $(x_i,x_i)\rightarrow (x,x)$ but this would imply that $\Delta$ is closed and hence every topological space would be Hausdorff. Clearly this is not the case.

My only thoughts are that perhaps some of the definitions I have used do not work for example a limit being well defined but so far my [checks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782702/a-non-hausdorff-space-with-unique-limit/1782779) seem to fail to provide an adequate issue with my blatant contradiction.

What's gone wrong?

Comment: A sequence can have, a priori, multiple limits. Take a space $X$ with more than two points and with topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$, then every point is the limit of every sequence.

Comment: @Alessandro so uniqueness of a limit is the Hausdorff property I am using in this "proof"? As I understand it non-Hausdorff spaces can have [unique limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782702/a-non-hausdorff-space-with-unique-limit/1782779) this cannot be the issue I have here.

Comment: The other error in your argument (other than what @Alessandro already pointed out) is that you think of limits of **sequences** only. A set is closed iff is contains all limits of **filters** (or **nets**) in the set. A non-Hausdoff space can have unique limits of all sequences, but not of all filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in the comments, if you're space is not Hausdorff, then sequences can have a priori multiple limit points. As also pointed out in the comments by @Andreas Blass, your space might not be Hausdorff, but such that every sequence has a unique limit (you can find an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782702/a-non-hausdorff-space-with-unique-limit/1782779)). However, the following hold:

> A space is Hausdorff if and only if every [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) has a unique limit

You can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573345/haussdorfness-iff-limits-of-all-nets-are-unique)

Answer (score 1):

If in a non-Hausdorff space $X$ the sequence $(x_n)$ has limits $a$ and $b$ with $a \neq b$ (this can happen!) then $(x_n,x_n)$ is a sequence in $\Delta$ that converges to $(a,b)$ (and also to $(b,a)$), both of which are not in $\Delta$. So your argument fails.

There are also non-Hausdorff spaces where sequence limits *are* unique (US spaces) but then another flaw is shown: for closedness in *general* spaces it is **not** enough to consider closedness under sequential limits, but filters or nets must be used.